# Mutiple Spring scheduled methods not working parallely

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-batch

We have a Spring Jobs project which contains multiple jobs which are invoked by 
placing @Scheduled(cron="${cronexp}") above the method to be invoked like below

```
@Scheduled(cron="${cron1}")
public void  task1() {
//processing
}


@Scheduled(cron="${cron2}")
public void  task2() {
//processing
}.
```

Now the problem I am facing is that task2 doesnt start processing if task is not yet finished.Is it a known issue with spring batch or some config setting so that all scheduled methods are able to execute parallely ?

Comment: Do you have a thread pool configured? If not nothing is executed in parallel.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for responding.but how should I add these tasks to task executor as these are called  spring internally

Comment: That will be done automatically but you have to tell the scheduler which thread pool to use. If you don't configure one executing will be done using a single thread, i.e. 1 task at a time.

Answer (score 2):

`@Scheduled` relies on the task executor defined in your application context. There is no magic there, `@Scheduled` will ask for an existing `TaskExecutor`, the way your threads are dispatched will depend on that.

You **do need** to set up the task executor that will be used by Spring to make it fit your needs. In short:

Ensure the task executor that is being used by Spring contains the minimum amount of threads you need, in this example, using old xml config, the maximum amount of simultaneous threads will be 5.

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
  <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
  <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</bean>
```

As another way of remarking the importance of taking consciousness of what's going on under the hood, you could also use `@EnableAsync` in java config, that annotation, will enable you to use @Scheduled, @Async... and it will nicely register a `TaskExecutor` for you.

By default it will register a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` which uses **a new** thread every time an async action is invoked and has **no limits** by default in terms of number of threads. That is probably inconvenient from a performance point of view in many scenarios, being a pool probably a better approach to this situation.

Let me attach you a suggested configuration from [Spring Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) using a proper pool:

```
@Configuration
 @EnableAsync
 public class AppConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

     @Bean
     public MyAsyncBean asyncBean() {
         return new MyAsyncBean();
     }

     @Override
     public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
         ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
         executor.setCorePoolSize(7);
         executor.setMaxPoolSize(42);
         executor.setQueueCapacity(11);
         executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyExecutor-");
         executor.initialize();
         return executor;
     }

     @Override
     public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
         return MyAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
     }
 }
```